# getting specific language set on the android device

Tags: android, localization

I need a way to get current language set on the android device. For example, if the device language is English UK, I should get something like en-gb (or something similar to differentiate between English US etc). I tried using following methods, however none of them gives me required information.

For ex:

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() returns 2 character language code such as 'en'

Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage() returns display language like 'English'

Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language() returns 3 character language like 'eng'
```

Please let me know if there is any other way to find current device languange.

Regards,
Bsengar

Comment: You can get a string representation with locale.toString(). If you want just want the country code it's locale.getCountry().

Comment: Thanks Krylez for your response.